# Jaxb: Dealing with an optional element in rest webservice response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, jaxb

I have an Object Ticket which has an element totalNoOfTickets associated with it. I use this object Ticket in many methods of my restful service. However, i only need the element 'totalNoOfTickets' for one method only and not others....

For example, in one of my method, i say...

```
Ticket.setTotalNoOfTickets(7);
```

I do not use this totalNoOfTickets in other methods. Hence,i do not set it in other methods.

Now in my Ticket.java...I have

```
public class Ticket
    extends ActionType {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Tickets")
    @XmlElement(name = "Ticket")
    protected List<Ticket> tickets;

    @XmlElement(name = "TotalNumOfTickets")
    protected int totalNumofTickets;

    public int getTotalNumofTickets() {
        return totalNumofTickets;
    }

    public void setTotalNumofTickets(int totalNumoftokens) {
        this.totalNumofTickets = totalNumoftickets;
    }
```

In method responses, where i set the totalNumoftickets, response contains:

```
<TotalNumOfTickets>7</TotalNumOfTickets>
```

But, even in responses, where i do not need totalNumoftickets, reponse contains

```
<TotalNumOfTickets>0</TotalNumOfTickets>
```

Is there any way in Jax-B where it would not have

```
<TotalNumOfTickets>0</TotalNumOfTickets>
```

in the response of methods, where i do not set totalNumoftickets?...can i use that element optionally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will not marshal `null` values.  You could change `totalNumofTickets` field/property to an `Integer` and have the value null when you don't want to marshal it.

```
public class Ticket
    extends ActionType {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Tickets")
    @XmlElement(name = "Ticket")
    protected List<Ticket> tickets;

    @XmlElement(name = "TotalNumOfTickets")
    protected Integer totalNumofTickets;

    public Integer getTotalNumofTickets() {
        return totalNumofTickets;
    }

    public void setTotalNumofTickets(Integer totalNumoftokens) {
        this.totalNumofTickets = totalNumoftickets;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

Comment: thanks...that worked...I should have known this earlier...but never mind, atleast know it now...